# Getting feature set for geoprocessing service?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am calling a geoprocessing service in a web app. The geoprocessing service has one parameter (a feature set). But I am not sure how to find the parameter in the javascript code to send it to the geoprocessing since I am using an editor widget to first create the polygon and then run the geoprocessing service.

Can you take a look at my code and tell me how I reference a feature set from the editor widget results?

```
], function(
    Map, BasemapGallery, arcgisUtils, Edit, 
    ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, FeatureLayer,
    Query, QueryTask,
    SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, 
    Editor, TemplatePicker, 
    esriConfig, jsapiBundle,
    arrayUtils, parser, keys,  

    borderContainer, contentPane, titlePane,
    dom, on
  ) {
    parser.parse();       

    // snapping is enabled for this sample - change the tooltip to reflect this
    jsapiBundle.toolbars.draw.start = jsapiBundle.toolbars.draw.start +  "<br>Press <b>ALT</b> to enable snapping";

    // refer to "Using the Proxy Page" for more information:  https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html
    esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy";    


    esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://tfsgis-iisd01:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");

    map = new Map("map", { 
      basemap: "hybrid",

      center: [-98.57, 30.98],
      zoom: 6,
      slider: true 
    });

    map.on("layers-add-result", initEditor);


    var ActivityArea = new FeatureLayer("http://tfsgis-iisd01:6080/arcgis/rest/services/MyMapService2/FeatureServer/1",{
      mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND, 
      outFields: ['*']
    });

    var ActivityPoint = new FeatureLayer("http://tfsgis-iisd01:6080/arcgis/rest/services/MyMapService2/FeatureServer/0",{
      mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND, 
      outFields: ['*']
    });

    var stewardship = new FeatureLayer("http://tfsgis-iisd01:6080/arcgis/rest/services/MyMapService2/FeatureServer/2",{
      mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND, 
      outFields: ['*']
    });

    map.addLayers([ActivityArea,ActivityPoint,stewardship]);




    function initEditor(evt) {

      var templateLayers = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function(result){
        return result.layer;

      });


      var templatePicker = new TemplatePicker({
        featureLayers: templateLayers,
        grouping: true,
        rows: "auto",
        columns: 3
      }, "templateDiv");
      templatePicker.startup();

      var layers = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function(result) {
        return { featureLayer: result.layer };
      });

      var settings = {
        map: map,
        templatePicker: templatePicker,
        layerInfos: layers,
        toolbarVisible: true,
        createOptions: {
          polylineDrawTools:[ Editor.CREATE_TOOL_FREEHAND_POLYLINE ],
          polygonDrawTools: [ Editor.CREATE_TOOL_FREEHAND_POLYGON,
            Editor.CREATE_TOOL_CIRCLE,
            Editor.CREATE_TOOL_TRIANGLE,
            Editor.CREATE_TOOL_RECTANGLE
          ]
        },
        toolbarOptions: {
          reshapeVisible: true
        }


      };





      var params = {settings: settings};    
      var myEditor = new Editor(params,'editorDiv');
      //define snapping options
      var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
        SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CROSS, 
        15, 
        new SimpleLineSymbol(
          SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
          new Color([255, 0, 0, 0.5]), 
          5
        ), 
        null
      );
      map.enableSnapping({
        snapPointSymbol: symbol,
        tolerance: 20,
        snapKey: keys.ALT
      });

      myEditor.startup();



    }



     on(dom.byId("button"),"click", function() {
    gp = new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor("http://tfsgis-iisd01:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalcFeaturesStewardshipOneParameter3/GPServer/CalcFeaturesStewardshipOneParameter")
    //gp.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference


    var features= [];

    var selectGraphics = featureLayer.getSelectedFeatures();

    features.push(selectGraphics);
    var featureSet = new esri.tasks.FeatureSet();

    featureSet.features = features;


    var params = {Stewardship:featureSet}

    gp.submitJob(params, completeCallback , statusCallback)



    });

    function completeCallback(jobInfo){

  }

  function statusCallback(jobInfo) {
    var status = jobInfo.jobStatus;
    if(status === "esriJobFailed"){
      alert(status);

    }
    else if (status === "esriJobSucceeded"){
      alert(status);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This isn't at all easy to follow. The code you've included looks like a partial snapshot of a much larger code base, and the intent is far from clear. Can you consider trying to make a smaller sample that shows the particular issue you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're very close, have a look at the following URLs:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_gp_creating.html
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_gp_parameters.html
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_gp_running.html

One thing to check is that execute is for synchronous GP tasks and submitJob is for async tasks.